# Integer Linear Programming special case

Tags: algorithm, integer

I am trying to solve a special case of Integer Linear Programming Problem, but I seem to be stack on the algorithm.

Specifically, suppose you have some binary variable `x_{1}, ... x_{n}` and some inequalities of the form:

```
i.e. x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{10} <= 2
```

Note, that the coefficients of the inequalities are all unity and the right hand side is always the number of variables in the left hand side minus 1.

Also, remember that the variables `x_{1}, ..., x_{n}` can take the values of 0 or 1.

This is a homework (to write a program) but I cannot find an algorithm to start.

I tried with DP and Network Flow, but nothing came out.

The objective function (got lost in the edit) is to maximize the sum:

```
x_{1} + ... + x_{n}
```

Comment: So basically, your solution set would be all possible values of the variables where at least one of them is zero - or, put another way, all possible replacements except the one single one where all variables are 1? Doesn't seem like you'd need linear or dynamic programming for that one...

Comment: Indeed. Well, network flow might work, but i cannot model the fact that a variable appears in many equations.

Comment: Ah... missed the bit about having multiple simultaneous equations/inequalities to solve... That does restrict the problem space a bit more...

Comment: Is it true that there always exist an optimal solution where at most one variable in each equation is set to zero? If so, we could reduce to Maximum independant Set. Notice that i expect a pseudopolynomial or-something algorithm, as seen by the time limits

Comment: What's the objective function?

Comment: Perhaps I'm being obtuse, but why is this not solvable using ordinary linear programming? Does LP stop working when the coefficients in the constraint matrix are all `0` or `1`? And what are you trying to minimize? In other words, what is wrong with the trivial solution where *x_n* = 0 for all *n*?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You can solve the LP, but the solution won't be integer unless there's a good reason like total unimodularity, which does not apply here.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ah, I see what you mean. Although without any constraints the result would still be all zeros.

Comment: I believe i have a reduction to Set Cover. You can view the problem as a bipartite graph. The left side will have the variables. The right side will have a sequence of numbers {1,...,m} representing the m equations. So, we need to pick the minimum left side nodes/variables to cover the (whole) right side. This minimum left side represents the variables you have to set to zero(right?). This is equivalent to the set cover where each variable creates a set, namely the one where this variable belongs to.

Comment: Yes, that does seem like a good approach.

Comment: This is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801835/given-an-amount-of-sets-with-numbers-find-a-set-of-numbers-not-including-any-of

Comment: @ZebraMan I think your reduction is to the "Hitting Set" problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation which is dual to Set Cover.

Comment: I was thinking something like http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/dydaktyka/2012-13/fpt/fpt_04_FSC-kociumaka.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to Set Cover: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Integer_linear_program_formulation. One way to see this easily is to replace `x_{i}` with `1-y{i}`, which gives an equivalent 0-1 linear programming problem, namely

```
maximize (1-y_{1}) + (1-y_{2}) + ... + (1-y_{n}) = n - (y_{1} + ... + y_{n}),
which is equivalent to minimizing y_{1} + ... + y_{n},

subject to the following family of inequalities indexed by j: 
  (1-y_{i_{1j}}) + (1-y_{i_{2j}}) + ... + (1-y_{i_{kj}) <= k-1,
which are equivalent to:
  y_{i_{1j}} + y_{i_{2j}} + ... + y_{i_kj} >= 1
```

The equivalent formulation of the problem is the 0-1 integer linear programming formulation of Set Cover.

A greedy algorithm will provide a reasonable approximation in this situation. Determine which of the `x_{i}` appear most often in constraints, and set it equal to 0. All of the constraints in which `x_{i0}` appears are now satisfied, so they can be removed from consideration, and the variable `x_{i0}` can be removed from objective. Repeat with the variable `x_{i1}` which appears most often in the remaining constraints, etc.

Alternatively, real linear programming will also provide an approximation.

Since Set Cover is NP-hard, the best exact solution you will be able to find will be exponential in time. A simple algorithm would just try all possibilities (run through all binary numbers from `x_{n}x_{n-1}...x_{1}x_{0} = 00...00` to `x_{n}x_{n-1}...x_{1}x_{0} = 11...11 = 2^(n+1)-1`. There are surely faster (but still exponential time) algorithms if you search.

Comment: In general, greedy algorithms are fast, but sub-optimal. Here's an easy counter example consisting of six equations (showing the coefficients) `0010` `0011` `1011` `0101` `1101` `0100`. Given that the order of the variables is `x3 x2 x1 x0`, then it's clear that `x0` covers 4 equations, yet the solution is `x2` and `x1` which each cover 3 equations.

Comment: Yup, thanks for that ... now the next question to ask: is there a dynamic programming algorithm?

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle: Have you ever studied "Branch and Bound"?

Comment: Yes, branch and bound would work but since the problem is NP-hard it will take exponential time. Exact 0-1 Integer Linear Programming solvers use branch and bound internally.

Comment: To show the problem's NP hard, don't you need to show that you can reduce set cover to the problem and not vice-versa?

Comment: The chain of reasoning is composed of logical equivalences. I'll correct my answer.